# Is it possible to change which output the audio is played through?

Tags: audio, htc-evo, earpiece

Is it possible to reroute audio (i.e. music) through the phone earpiece instead of the speaker? I've searched this site and Google extensively and haven't found anything yet.

If it matters, I'm on the HTC Evo 4G LTE (Sprint). I'm also rooted and have CM10.1 on my phone.

Comment: what exactly you are looking for?? please elaborate

Comment: @cyberwalker OP is wanting to play music without headset, but through in built ear-piece instead of speaker

Comment: Did you see the answer provided?

Comment: @sid Yeah, I was planning on accepting, but I lost track of time. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use an app like **[Earpiece](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.Earpiece&hl=en)**. It does what you want to do. You can pop Earpiece up on top of another application simply by holding down the SEARCH key. then check `Audio through earpiece`

[image]

On a side note, USE AT YOUR OWN RISK. Playing audio at high volumes, especially for a prolonged amount of time, *can damage speakers and/or hearing*.

Comment: Interesting find +1. Just looking at it - it states *Earpiece is free and Open Source.* but no linky to site hosting it... :\ Also reading the screenshot where the FAQ is showing, this is has ads and if you want to get rid of the ads, buy a commercial app from the same maker...

Comment: Use ABP(AdBlock Plus: https://adblockplus.org/en/android-install ) to block the ads.

Comment: The source code is at http://code.google.com/p/earpiece/ (BTW, there is version 1.08 there, which is not yet available at Google Play). Also ads were removed in version 1.04, but the screenshot was not updated.

Comment: The "audio boost" feature actually makes audio more silent for me on Huawei Honor 6. Useful since minimum level is too loud.

Comment: Seems this app no longer works on Android 11.