# Playing audio through phone call speaker

Tags: audio

Is there a newer method of routing audio to the phone call speaker (the speaker that you put your ear to)? [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/41234/360271) suggests using [Earpiece](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.Earpiece&hl=en&showAllReviews=true), but the app does not appear to work on Android 11 and up and hasn't been updated since 2015. Any suggestions?